# PDF file loads form fields very slowly

Tags: javascript, pdf, acrobat

I have made a fill-able PDF form with some automation which is supported by javascript. Every time I try to open my PDF, the form fields do not load but if I scroll down or zoom out, every content is then visible.
I tried optimizing my PDF but it doesn't help. Is there anything that I can do to improve the performance of the PDF.

Comment: I'd need to see a copy of the file.